# Named Entity Recognition - direct matching with a dictionary

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I would like to use named entity recognition (NER) to identify words or phrases in the text which align with clinical concepts.

I have a dictionary that contains the description of a diagnosis and its label code. Example of first 2 rows:

```
ICD10  ICD10Term
----------------
A00    Cholera
A000   Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae
```

Firstly, I wanted to start with a direct match with the dictionary but I am not sure how I should do it. Should I just search if the dictionary contains a certain string? Or should I use a package or a tool?

I found `spacy-lookup` : https://github.com/mpuig/spacy-lookup

I am not sure how I would use this package at a large scale as I have many txt files and the dictionary.

Also, is there any other package\tool that you would recommend me?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to first train your own NER model to do that.

Prepare your dataset as spaCy requires and then train your model. Then your model should be able to detect the entities.

Comment: Shouldn't I find the medical terminology in my dataset using direct maches or fuzzy matching? Some medical words have a different meaning together so I think I shouldn't tokenize before finding the medical terminology. Sorry, I am new in this field so I am not sure if it's correct what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `pretrain` function of spaCy https://spacy.io/api/cli#pretrain to update the Language Model to your domain first. Then train NER from scratch - https://spacy.io/usage/training#ner